# OpenCV read video files with multiple streams/tracks

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I have a video file that contains multiple streams as shown below using VLC media player:
[Video Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi0a1.png)

When I try to read it using Python + OpenCV using the following code:

```
vidObj = cv2.VideoCapture("video.avi")
ret, frame = vidObj.read()
```

I can only read the first track of the video. How can I read all the video tracks at the same time?

Comment: The video is generated by a frame grabber called Epiphan, which support capturing multiple video streams at the same time. That's why it has multiple  video tracks.

Comment: Running a quick search, it seems multistream videos are not that common to work with. If no one comes up with a solution, I suggest using something like `ffmpeg` to divide the streams in to separate videos before working on them.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for the answer. Can you explain it in more details about how to use ffmpeg to divide them? Thanks.

Comment: @poisondeathray's [answer](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/319455-How-to-Demux-avi-with-multiple-video-streams#post1978557) (#4) here should help you. Since there are multiple streams and not only 2, you should probably write a script that runs the `ffmeg -map` command depending on the input video. If you have any trouble, please create a new question with any issues that come up.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could tell, OpenCV does not allow choosing video stream, so this is not possible. However, you can do it rather easily with `ffmpeg` command line utilities:

```py
import numpy as np
import json
import subprocess

def videoInfo(filename):
    proc = subprocess.run([
        *"ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams".split(),
        filename
    ], capture_output=True)
    proc.check_returncode()
    return json.loads(proc.stdout)

def readVideo(filename):
    cmd = ["ffmpeg", "-i", filename]
    streams = 0
    for stream in videoInfo(filename)["streams"]:
        index = stream["index"]
        if stream["codec_type"] == "video":
            width = stream["width"]
            height = stream["height"]
            cmd += "-map", f"0:{index}"
            streams = streams + 1
    cmd += "-f", "rawvideo", "-pix_fmt", "rgb24", "-"
    shape = np.array([streams, height, width, 3])
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
        while True:
            data = proc.stdout.read(shape.prod())  # One byte per each element
            if not data:
                return
            yield np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)
```

Note that the code reads all video streams and assumes that each has the same resolution. It lacks proper error handling but got the job done in my scientific project.

For example, reading stereoscopic stream:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for left, right in readVideo("testvideo.mkv"):
    plt.imshow(left)
    plt.show()
    plt.imshow(right)
    plt.show()
```