# How do I capture multiple camera streams with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, streaming, rtsp

I want to Multiple CCTV Viewer.
Display video 20 different RTSP sources in single window.
Without using PyQt5.
Using cv2.hconcat or np.hstack, the program is forced to shut down.
So I'm trying to use multiprocessing and pygame.

Below is the code I tried.

[Camera.py]

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing as mp
import imutils
import pygame
import numpy as np

class CameraWidget():
    """Independent camera feed
    Uses threading to grab IP camera frames in the background

    @param width - Width of the video frame
    @param height - Height of the video frame
    @param stream_link - IP/RTSP/Webcam link
    @param aspect_ratio - Whether to maintain frame aspect ratio or force into fraame
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height, stream_link=0, aspect_ratio=False, parent=None, deque_size=1):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialize deque used to store frames read from the stream
        self.deque = mp.Queue(deque_size)

        # Slight offset is needed since PyQt layouts have a built in padding
        # So add offset to counter the padding
        self.offset = 16
        self.screen_width = width - self.offset
        self.screen_height = height - self.offset
        self.maintain_aspect_ratio = aspect_ratio

        self.camera_stream_link = stream_link

        # Flag to check if camera is valid/working
        self.online = False
        self.capture = None

        self.load_network_stream()

        # Start background frame grabbing
        self.get_frame_thread = mp.Process(target=self.get_frame, args=())
        self.get_frame_thread.daemon = True
        self.get_frame_thread.start()


        print('Started camera: {}'.format(self.camera_stream_link))

    def load_network_stream(self):
        """Verifies stream link and open new stream if valid"""

        def load_network_stream_thread():
            if self.verify_network_stream(self.camera_stream_link):
                self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera_stream_link)
                self.online = True

        self.load_stream_thread = mp.Process(target=load_network_stream_thread, args=())
        self.load_stream_thread.daemon = True
        self.load_stream_thread.start()

    def verify_network_stream(self, link):
        """Attempts to receive a frame from given link"""

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            return False
        cap.release()
        return True

    def get_frame(self):
        """Reads frame, resizes, and converts image to pixmap"""

        while True:
            try:
                if self.capture.isOpened() and self.online:
                    # Read next frame from stream and insert into deque
                    status, frame = self.capture.read()
                    if status:
                        self.deque.append(frame)
                    else:
                        self.capture.release()
                        self.online = False
                else:
                    # Attempt to reconnect
                    print('attempting to reconnect', self.camera_stream_link)
                    self.load_network_stream()
                #     self.spin(2)
                # self.spin(.001)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def set_frame(self):
        """Sets pixmap image to video frame"""

        if not self.online:
            # self.spin(1)
            return

        if self.deque and self.online:
            # Grab latest frame
            frame = self.deque[-1]

            # Keep frame aspect ratio
            if self.maintain_aspect_ratio:
                self.frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=self.screen_width)
            # Force resize
            else:
                self.frame =  cv2.resize(frame, dsize=(384, 216), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

            # Add timestamp to cameras
            cv2.rectangle(self.frame, (self.screen_width - 190, 0), (self.screen_width, 50), color=(0, 0, 0),
                          thickness=-1)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, dsize=(384, 216), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = np.rot90(frame)
            frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame)

    def get_video_frame(self):
        return self.video_frame
```

[main.py]

```
import sys
from Camera import CameraWidget
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def exit_application():
    """Exit program event handler"""

    sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    urls = ['rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.43:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0',
            'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp',
            'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.47:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0',
            'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.47:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0',
            'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.47:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0',
            'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.47:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0',
            'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.47:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0',
            'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.47:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0']
    cams=[]
    for i in len(urls):
        CameraWidget(1920 // 3, 1080 // 3, urls[i])

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1920, 1080])
    try:
        while True:
            screen.blit(frame, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    sys.exit(0)

    except (KeyboardInterrupt,SystemExit):
        pygame.quit()
```

.

This is the code I referred to.

I want to use
[this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592291/how-to-capture-multiple-camera-streams-with-opencv) using pygame.

Comment: Does this help ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58824909/opencv-read-video-files-with-multiple-streams-tracks)

Comment: @Vitor Pereira Matias Thanks. But I'm trying to use rtsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a multi-camera viewer, OpenCV, and pygame. i see some mistake i your code at least.
first set up the pygame window and initialize camera capture objects for the specified RTSP URLs.
then create separate threads to capture frames from each camera and display them using pygame.
The frames are arranged side by side in the pygame window.
This revised code allows you to view multiple RTSP camera streams in a single window using pygame.

```py
import sys
import pygame
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import threading

# Define the RTSP URLs of the cameras you want to view
camera_urls = [
    'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.43:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0',
    'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp',
    'rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.47:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0',
]

# Set up pygame
pygame.init()
screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Create a list to store the camera capture objects
capture_objects = []

# Initialize the camera capture objects
for url in camera_urls:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print(f"Failed to open camera: {url}")
        continue
    capture_objects.append(cap)

# Create a list to store the camera frames
frames = [None] * len(capture_objects)

# Function to capture frames from each camera
def capture_frames(camera_index):
    while True:
        ret, frame = capture_objects[camera_index].read()
        if not ret:
            print(f"Camera {camera_index} disconnected.")
            break
        frames[camera_index] = frame

# Start threads to capture frames from each camera
threads = []
for i in range(len(capture_objects)):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=capture_frames, args=(i,))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

try:
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        # Display frames from each camera
        frame_width = screen_width // len(capture_objects)
        frame_height = screen_height
        for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
            if frame is not None:
                frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=frame_width)
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame = np.rot90(frame)
                frame_surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame)
                screen.blit(frame_surface, (i * frame_width, 0))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)  # Adjust the frame rate as needed

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Release camera capture objects and quit
for cap in capture_objects:
    cap.release()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

replace the RTSP URLs, and this code should allow you to view multiple camera streams using pygame.